# Xpage with multiple forms and data sources create empty documents

Tags: forms, xpages, lotus-domino

- I have a two simple forms (Form1 and Form2). They have only one field
  each (field1). I created two custom controls. They are identical except
  cc1 has data source defined as Form1  and cc2 has a data source of
  Form 2.
- Each custom control has one inputbox bound to the field1 field    of
  the corresponding data source, and one submit button. I create an
  Xpage and pull both custom controls into the page.
- If I preview and    fill out the input boxes on the Xpage in a
  browser, when I click on    any of the submit buttons, two documents
  will be created based on the two forms in the       domino database.
- I tried to use partial refresh/execution and lots of other things.
  No matter what I do, I always get empty documents of both Forms.

XPage:

```
<xp:div styleClass="container" style="margin-top:20px">
   <xp:div styleClass="row">
     <xc:cc1></xc:cc1>
     <xc:cc2></xc:cc2>
   </xp:div>
 </xp:div>
```

Custom control 1

```
 <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="form1" formName="form1"></xp:dominoDocument>
  </xp:this.data>
  <xp:div id="formDiv1" styleClass="col-sm-4">
    <xp:form>
      <xp:label value="Form 1" styleClass="h3"></xp:label>
      <xp:div styleClass="form-group">
        <xp:label value="Field 1" styleClass="control-label"></xp:label>
        <xp:inputText value="#{form1.field1}"></xp:inputText>
      </xp:div>
      <xp:button value="Submit Form1" id="form1Btn">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="true" refreshId="formDiv1"
          execMode="partial" execId="formDiv1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:button>
    </xp:form>
```

Custom control 2

```
 <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="form2" formName="form2"></xp:dominoDocument>
  </xp:this.data>
  <xp:div id="formDiv1" styleClass="col-sm-4">
    <xp:form>
      <xp:label value="Form 2" styleClass="h3"></xp:label>
      <xp:div styleClass="form-group">
        <xp:label value="Field 1" styleClass="control-label"></xp:label>
        <xp:inputText value="#{form2.field1}"></xp:inputText>
      </xp:div>
      <xp:button value="Submit Form2" id="form2Btn">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="true" refreshId="formDiv1"
          execMode="partial" execId="formDiv1">
        </xp:eventHandler>
      </xp:button>
    </xp:form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A normal submit button gets the property `save="true"` and saves **all** data sources.

If you want to save only **one** data source then use the simple action `Save Document` and select the data source:

[image]

Set property `save="false"` in addition. Your button code would look like this then:

```xml
<xp:button
    id="form1Btn"
    value="Submit Form1">
    <xp:eventHandler
        event="onclick"
        submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete"
        immediate="false"
        save="false">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:saveDocument
                var="form1"></xp:saveDocument>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: That's excellent. Thanks, Knut. It's almost perfect. However, after clicking the submit button the input field does not refresh. Furthermore, if I enter a different value in the input box and click the submit button again, then the previous document will be overwritten instead of creating a new document with the new value.

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/14585187/2065611 might help you how to get a new document after saving the previous.

Comment: Yes, indeed. that was the answer!
But I had to add an extra line in the code:
ds.setFormName("form2");

Comment: Datasources also have a `scope` variable. To create a new document each time, set `scope="request"`. By default they're scoped to viewScope, so it's the same document as long as you're on that page. Setting it to requestScope means it's discarded at the end of each partial refresh.

Comment: Thanks, Paul. I added your solution below. It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code that works using Knut's suggestion:

Xpage

```
<xp:div styleClass="container" style="margin-top:20px">
    <xp:div styleClass="row">
      <xc:cc1></xc:cc1>
      <xc:cc2></xc:cc2>
    </xp:div>
  </xp:div>
```

cc1

```
<xp:panel id="formDiv1" styleClass="col-sm-4">
    <xp:this.data>
      <xp:dominoDocument var="form1" formName="form1"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:label value="Form 1" styleClass="h3"></xp:label>
    <xp:div styleClass="form-group">
      <xp:label value="Field 1" styleClass="control-label"></xp:label>
      <xp:inputText id="field1" value="#{form1.field1}"></xp:inputText>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="form1Btn">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false" execMode="partial"
        execId="formDiv1" refreshId="formDiv1">
        <xp:this.action>
          <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:saveDocument var="form1"></xp:saveDocument>
            <xp:executeScript>
              <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var panel = getComponent("formDiv1");
var ds = new com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData();
ds.setComponent(panel);
ds.setVar("form1");
ds.setFormName("form1");
panel.getData().clear();
panel.addData(ds);}]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
          </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
  </xp:panel>
```

cc2

```
<xp:panel id="formDiv2" styleClass="col-sm-4 ">
    <xp:this.data>
      <xp:dominoDocument var="form2" formName="form2"></xp:dominoDocument>
    </xp:this.data>
    <xp:label value="Form 2" styleClass="h3"></xp:label>
    <xp:div styleClass="form-group">
      <xp:label value="Field 1" styleClass="control-label"></xp:label>
      <xp:inputText id="field1" value="#{form2.field1}">
      </xp:inputText>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:button value="Submit Form2" id="form2Btn">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false" execMode="partial"
        execId="formDiv2" refreshId="formDiv2">
        <xp:this.action>
          <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:saveDocument var="form2"></xp:saveDocument>
            <xp:executeScript>
              <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
var panel = getComponent("formDiv2");
var ds = new com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoDocumentData();
ds.setComponent(panel);
ds.setVar("form2");
ds.setFormName("form2");
panel.getData().clear();
panel.addData(ds);}]]></xp:this.script>
            </xp:executeScript>
          </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
  </xp:panel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Paul Wither's suggestion of using requestScope scope for the datasources made the code quite a bit simpler:

XPage

```
<xp:div styleClass="container" style="margin-top:20px">
    <xp:div styleClass="row">
      <xc:cc1></xc:cc1>
      <xc:cc2></xc:cc2>
    </xp:div>
```

custom control 1

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
  <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="form1" formName="form1" scope="request"></xp:dominoDocument>
  </xp:this.data>
  <xp:div id="formDiv1" styleClass="col-sm-4">
    <xp:label value="Form 1" styleClass="h3"></xp:label>
    <xp:div styleClass="form-group">
      <xp:label value="Field 1" styleClass="control-label"></xp:label>
      <xp:inputText id="field1" value="#{form1.field1}"></xp:inputText>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:button value="Save" id="form1Btn">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false" execMode="partial" execId="formDiv1"
        refreshId="formDiv1">
        <xp:this.action>
          <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:saveDocument var="form1"></xp:saveDocument>
          </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[x$("#{id:field1}").val("");]]></xp:this.onComplete>
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
  </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```

custom control 2

```
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
  <xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="form2" formName="form2" scope="request"></xp:dominoDocument>
  </xp:this.data>
  <xp:div id="formDiv2" styleClass="col-sm-4 ">
    <xp:label value="Form 2" styleClass="h3"></xp:label>
    <xp:div styleClass="form-group">
      <xp:label value="Field 1" styleClass="control-label"></xp:label>
      <xp:inputText id="field1" value="#{form2.field1}">
      </xp:inputText>
    </xp:div>
    <xp:button value="Submit Form2" id="form2Btn">
      <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" immediate="false" save="false" execMode="partial" 
      execId="formDiv2" refreshId="formDiv2">
        <xp:this.action>
          <xp:actionGroup>
            <xp:saveDocument var="form2"></xp:saveDocument>
          </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
        <xp:this.onComplete><![CDATA[x$("#{id:field1}").val("");]]></xp:this.onComplete>
      </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
  </xp:div>
</xp:view>
```